# How to conditionally add a clickable checkbox in google-sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried:

`=if(B11="","","☐")`

But I wanted to add a clickable checkbox and not just the symbol.

Comment: I think the tick box is a UI wrapper for controlling a cell's value. It's not just a symbol you can add to the sheet. (You *can* change the font color to white with conditional formatting, but the tick box is still clickable.) Did you have a particular problem you were trying to solve with this? Perhaps there's a workaround.

Comment: I don't think you can do this via formulas. You could do this programmatically with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), but I'm not sure whether that would be appropriate for your situation.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I'm trying to add an unchecked checkbox to all every line (existing an future-added one) in a sheet.

Comment: @Iamblichus I'm trying to add an unchecked checkbox to all every line (existing an future-added one) in a sheet.

Comment: So you want to add a checkbox to every row in which column `B` is not empty? You could do this with a Google Apps Script `onEdit` trigger, so that every time column B is edited, the corresponding cell in the row would be updated (either by creating the checkbox or by removing it). Do you think that would be appropriate for you? If that's the case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so sheet does not have a way to hide/show validation checkboxes, but I did find a work-around.

[image]

1. Add the checkboxes via Data/Data Validation
2. Set the fill color to black
3. Set the text color to white

Now, set up conditional formatting using a custom formula

```
=C20=""
```

1. Set text color to none
2. Set fill color to white

I built a tab in this sheet call Checkboxes so you can make a copy and experiment. In this sheet I just added the checkboxes using the Insert/Checkbox instead of via Data/Data Validation

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qbLOjTdzISICTKyUp_jK6gZbQCt-OwtDYYy3HNJygeE/edit#gid=1995409740

Comment: how can I create checkboxes to all the lines (existing an future-added one) in a sheet?

Comment: All the rows do have checkboxes but with the conditional formatting they look like they are hidden. Feel free to change the cell and text colors to suit your needs if you want the checkboxes to show regardless.